Remove cookies from request in middleware
we have a remote API server that gets overwhelmed by requests with too long headers so we'd like to remove cookies included in request as they have no use at the API server that is satisfied with Bearer token. Hasn't been an issue before but after implementing SSO auth w/ Keycloak provider, returned tokens way longer than those returned by Credentials provider causing the API server to choke up returning 431 error.
I've tried to remove cookies in many places including axios client-side request (interception, withCredentials: false) and middleware on server-side, but they always find a way in - confirmed by debugging a custom server where I redirected requests. Debugged NextJs server a bit and it seems to simply put all headers from request to redirect response.
middleware.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import withAuth from 'next-auth/middleware'

export default withAuth(
  function middleware({ nextUrl, url, cookies }) {
    const { pathname } = nextUrl

    const firstPath = pathname.split('/')[1]

    if (firstPath === 'our-api') {
      const response = NextResponse.rewrite(
        new URL(
          `${'http://localhost:1234'}${pathname}${
            process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? '/' : ''
          }`,
          url
        )
      )
      // clear cookies here
      
      return response
    }

    return NextResponse.next()
  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: () => true,
    },
  }
)

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!_next/static|favicon.ico|).*)', '/', '/our-api/:path*'],
}


solved by redirecting to another api route, where i perform manual request using axios filtering request data and headers
